# Upgrading default SQL server express of SharePoint 2010 for reporting services

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server

I need to upgrade default SQL server express of SharePoint 2010 with SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services. What are the things I should keep in mind before upgrading?

Thanking you in advance

Comment: What version of SQL Server is currently installed on the server?

Comment: Currently SQL Server 2008 Express is installed on the server.